# Disabling a Windows Form Closing button

Tags: c#, methods

After hours of Googling on this subject matter, I found the following code snippet which effectively does disable only the close button of a form.

```
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
     get
     {
           CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
           myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
           return myCp;
     }
}
```

Now instead of just writing this same snippet in every form, I'm trying to figure out a way to package it into possibly a static method of a class so that I can class it by just one line from anywhere.

But I have faced a problem doing that because this snippet is also an overridden method therefore I don't know how I can put it in to another static method.

I tried the following

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Common
    {
        private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
                myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
                return myCp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws this error : *'WindowsFormsApplication1.Common.CreateParams': no suitable method found to override*

My question is how can I make this snippet reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable/Disable/Hide Close button in C# windows forms

You can check [this](http://dotnetcodelearner.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/79/)

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a base class which inherits from the `Form` class, and then make all your forms inherited from that class.

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
            myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
            return myCp;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
//your form code
}
```